# Send ARKit camera position and quaternion on OSC (SwiftOSC)

Tags: ios, swift, arkit

I'm currently starting to learn Swift to develop an app as a part of my research. I'm ok with python but I can't seem to wrap my head around using Swift and Xcode.  I've been able to print accelerometer data on screen, and send values over OSC. However, I need help:

Find `ARKit` camera position (X,Y,Z),
Send these values over OSC.

I've set up the ARSession and set the ARDelegate etc, and set up a function to get the position values from the transform matrix, but I cannot seem to be able to display any data on screen and send over OSC. The ARKIT code is below. The first code break is just an example of using SwiftOSC, it should be easy to implement once I am able to get the ARKit data.

I know that this may be pretty simple but I can't get it working! If anyone is willing to help me doing that, it would be amazing. And if someone is willing to work with me on Zoom or Meets, my thesis grant will be able to give honorarium compensation for your time.

Thanks in advance!

```swift
   override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        motionManager.accelerometerUpdateInterval = (1/60)
        
        motionManager.startAccelerometerUpdates(to: OperationQueue.current!) {(data, error)in
            if let myData = data{
                let x = myData.acceleration.x
                let y = myData.acceleration.y
                let z = myData.acceleration.z
                self.xAccel.text = "x \(Double(x))"
                let message = OSCMessage(OSCAddressPattern("/accelx"), Double(x))
                client.send(message)
                let message_y = OSCMessage(OSCAddressPattern("/accely"), Double(y))
                client.send(message_y)
                let message_z = OSCMessage(OSCAddressPattern("/accelz"), Double(z))
                client.send(message_z)
                
            }
        }
        
    }
```

However, I can't seem to access camera position using ARKit:

```
import UIKit
import SceneKit
import ARKit


extension ViewController: ARSessionDelegate {
    
    func session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) {
        let transform = frame.camera.transform
        var position = transform.columns.3
        print(position.x, position.y, position.z)     //Get (x,y,z) and print
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate {
    
    

    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    
    
        // Set the view's delegate
        sceneView.delegate = self
        
        // Show statistics such as fps and timing information
        sceneView.showsStatistics = true
        
        // Create a new scene
        let scene = SCNScene(named: "art.scnassets/ship.scn")!
        
        // Set the scene to the view
        sceneView.scene = scene
    }
    
    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
        
        // Create a session configuration
        let configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()

        // Run the view's session
        sceneView.session.run(configuration)

// How to call function and assign position.[x,y,z], to variable to read on screen and send on OSC? So far I can't see any data at all.
        
    
    }
    
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)
        
        // Pause the view's session
        sceneView.session.pause()
    }
```

It always returns zero, or nothing at all.

Comment: This seems like it should be three parts:

1. How do I let the user specify an IP/hostname, port, and OSC address?
2. How do I get the camera position and rotation from ARKit?
3. How do I send the data from question 2 to the destination from question 1 using SwiftOSC?

Comment: @hush-entangle I got the OSC working with accelerometer data today. And to allow user input for IP/hostname and port. I am still stuck on how to access the ARKit camera position. But sending via OSC should be pretty much the same as accel data. Any chance you can help?

Comment: ARKit is the part of this I know the least about. Looking through the docs, it seems ARKit delivers to your application a series of ARFrame objects. These objects should have a camera property which is an instance of an ARCamera object. That object then has a transform property and an eulerAngles property which seem to be the positional data you're looking for. Beyond that, I'm not sure what help I can offer.

Comment: @hush-entangle Yes that is what I'm trying to access. I have a function that prints the (x,y,z) locations from the transform matrix, but I can't figure out how to call that function to assign it to a variable and display in a textbox on screen (because I can't get debug info in Xcode on my Mac from iPhone right now)

Comment: My reading of https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arsession is ARSCNView creates a session for you, so the delegate's session(_ session: ARSession, didUpdate frame: ARFrame) method never gets called. You could set up a Timer (a way of scheduling a function; https://learnappmaking.com/timer-swift-how-to/) which then pulls the sceneView.session.currentFrame and operates on it. Kind of gross, but it should work.